# Error when trying to extract one frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.

I need to extract a frame from a video to generate a thumbnail, and I'm using the next call to FFmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i /projectes/macba/TEMP/video_test/DIG_A-HIS-04943_001_h.mov -r 1 -ss 00:00:59 -t 120:-1 test.jpg`

It results in this error

`[buffer @ 0x174efe0] Buffering several frames is not supported. Please consume all available frames before adding a new one.`

and doesn't generate the image.

I'm not used to using FFmpeg and I'm having trouble spotting the problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrade](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux) !! 0.8 is probably 7-8 years old.

Then use

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:59 -i input -vframes 1 test.jpg
```

Comment: It not depends on me, the upgrade, but I will ask to the SysAdmins. But if not possible to upgrade do you have any idea?